# Import Large csv data into postgres DB using Rails 4.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, csv, sidekiq

I have a large CSV file, about 100k rows that I need to import into my Postgres Database. I have the option of using Sidekiq as well if I should go that route.

I saw the option of using Raw SQL, and it seems that may be the fastest option:

```
COPY test_data FROM '/path/to/csv/test_data.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;
```

Is that faster than spinning up asynchronous sidekiq jobs? If it is, how would I write this SQL statement within my controller in Rails 4.0.0?

Comment: The very fastest option is usually to split the CSV into several chunks, and `COPY` each chunk in parallel. To use `COPY`, you can use the Pg gem directly rather than fight with Rails - see the docs on `Pg::Connection`. I can't link you to docs right not because the doc site seems to be down.

Comment: I think @Craig was looking for this: http://rubydoc.info/gems/pg/PG/Connection:copy_data